# Adding Facebook profiles to Address Book

Tags: contacts, facebook

I see that Address Book has a field for entering a friend's Facebook profile. However, many of my friends don't have an actual facebook username (ie a profile at facebook.com/username), but just the old user ID (facebook.com/profile.php?id=blah). Is there any way to make it work with those?

Also, how can I sync information from Facebook (eg birthdays) with my address book? Is there a way to do that and veto updates, like with iSync? Sometimes people have fake information on Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the URL for your friend's profile on Facebook, and paste it into the Facebook profile field in the card editor.  Disregard the fact that the editor shows "User Name" placeholder text in this field; the URL works fine.  After saving the card, you can click on the Facebook label to the left of the URL, and you'll get a menu that includes "View Profile" and "View Photos".

I tested this on Lion both when using a profile URL, and when using a new Facebook username.  The "View Photos" action does not work when saving a profile URL, but both actions work when saving a Facebook username.

Answer (score 1):

The tool that best matches what you're trying to do is http://danauclair.com/addressbooksync/ (that I know of).

Though it works under Lion, I do not believe it is Lion aware (as of 06 Aug 2011) hence it does not make use of the new "Profile->Facebook" field. Matching is done by heuristic, as far as I can see.

While addressbooksync allows some manual match-up and specifying of fields to sync, it isn't comprehensive. Fake and/or incomplete information will be synced; it will not ask you for confirmation.